# Is it possible to add individual from CSV file into ontology in rapidminer?

Tags: ontology, instances, rapidminer

I made an ontology and add instances or individuals manually,however if I want to add the data from CSV file into ontology, Is it possible in rapid miner?I know how to load CSV file in rapid miner.But how to add data in ontology using rapid miner?

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Hello, I made an ontology having class name Song. Now to add individuals instead of adding manually I am having CSV file containing all the name of songs.So this process I want to do in Rapid miner.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do. What is your definition of ontology?

Comment: I am making a music ontology, having classes song,artist.Data Properties of Songs are name_is, Time_of_Song.Now I want to add names of songs using individual of name_is of songs using a CSV file that have list of songs.I want to do this in Rapid miner.

Comment: Is your ontology a file. If so, why not use the `Write CSV` operator to create it?

Comment: Hello, My ontology file is in rdf format. I am having CSV file.I want to just insert individual in my ontology through this CSV file.

Comment: You should have mentioned RDF at the beginning. I would use the R or Python extensions and a suitable package to do the heavy lifting. A quick Google reveals an R package called RDF. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Thank you for the help.I will try.

Comment: If you have a sample code or any material related to this please can you share with me.